# How to iterate for loop in django python template

Tags: python, django, templates

I am currently creating a template and I want to iterate a list however this is going to be tricky because I would like to display only 5 items per line then the next items will go to the next line. I would Like the display an image between every 5 items.

this is my list:

```
    myList = [{'id':1, 'image':'image1.jpg'},
{'id':2, 'image':'image2.jpg'},
{'id':3, 'image':'image3.jpg'},
{'id':4, 'image':'image4.jpg'},
{'id':5, 'image':'image5.jpg'},
{'id':6, 'image':'image6.jpg'},
{'id':7, 'image':'image7.jpg'},
{'id':8, 'image':'image8.jpg'},
{'id':9, 'image':'image9.jpg'},
{'id':10, 'image':'image10.jpg'},
{'id':11, 'image':'image11.jpg'},]
```

this is my template

myList.html

```
{% for a in myList %}

<a href="{{a.image}}">{{a.id}}</a>
{% if forloop.counter == 5%}
 <img src="{{a.image}}">
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

and those images are link from each items.

this is what i would like to see

```
1 2 3 4 5
<image>
6 7 8 9 10
<image>
11
```

if I click each item, the image will display in the next line.

**Here is a sample image on how it works**
[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp6rF.png)

- If number 1 is clicked the image1 will be shown in the green box, the
  same way for number 2 to number 5.
- If number 9 is clicked the image9    will be shown in the green box,
  the same way for number 6 to number
    10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:5 %}
```

Comment: Thank you but I still can not make it work as to what I expect to be seen. I really appreciate your help

Comment: That click logic is another question to which you haven't stated what you have already tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `divisibleby` like this: 
    {% for a in myList %}

```
<a href="{{a.image}}">{{a.id}}</a>
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:5 %}
 <img src="{{a.image}}">
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby) to the documentation.

Comment: I have tried it however it gives me the same result. I could only click the link of every 5th item. But I can not show the images of the 1st to 4th item. :(